# Apple store custom payment solution possible for poor country?

Tags: ios, mobile, google-play

We are working on a mobile application for a poor country and need to add a subscription fee.

The problem isn't the 30% Apple or Google takes but more they're payment gateway. Most people don't have a credit card or even a bank account.

So we need to use a service where they can go anywhere to deposit money and transfer it with their phone. But if we implement that service we can against Apple & Google for they subscription police.

I wonder if some of you saw that issue before and if you have an idea for a workaround other than having the subscription on another website that we can not advertise on the app?

Comment: I'd say this is more a legal matter than a development related one. Epic games are currently in a legal battle over the same thing. I think this would be off topic for stack overflow. It **might** be better posted on https://law.stackexchange.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apple's App Store guidelines are clear; you must use in app purchase. In many countries Apple provides iTunes gift cards that can be purchased and used to add credit to an App Store account. Is this an option?